# como validar módulos con php y msql

Tags: php, codeigniter

mi problema es el siguiente.

Tengo unos usuarios, entre ellos se encuentra el administrador, pero tengo problemas al mostrar los módulos para el administrador los cuales deben ser todos, pero ellos desprenden desde una categoria.

```
<div class="d-flex toggled" id="wrapper">

<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-heading">Módulos</div>
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <a href="#collapse1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="collapse"><?php echo $modulo;?><span class="caret"></span><span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($modulos as $item):
                    ?>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $item->modulo?></li>  <!-- /es aqui donde se muestran los módulos -->
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
        <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary menu" id="menu-toggle"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button> -->


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link home" data-toggle="pill" href="#home"><i
                            class="fas fa-home principal"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link"><?php echo $nombre;?> <i class="fas fa-user principal"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link menu" id="menu-toggle" href="">Menú <i class="fa fa-list principal"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link menu" id="menu-toggle" href="<?= base_url("login/cerrar_session") ?>"><i
                            class="fa fa-power-off principal"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">

    </div>
</div>
<!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
```

Mi controlador

```
function listar_modulos(){
    $fun1 = $this->recibe_usuario();
    $nom_usuario = $fun1->nombre;
    $negocio = $fun1->und_negocio;
    $nivel = '';
    switch ($negocio) {
        case "alkomprar":
            $nivel = 1;
            break;
        case "alkosto":
            $nivel = 2;
            break;
        case "":
            $nivel1 = 1;
            $nivel2 = 2;

            $nivel = $nivel1.$nivel2;
            echo $nivel;
            break;
    }
    $datos['nombre'] = $nom_usuario;
    $datos['modulo'] = $negocio;
    $datos['modulos'] = $this->Principal_model->listar_modulos($nivel);
    $this->load->view('front_end/navbar', $datos);
}
```

Mi modelo

```
function listar_modulos($nivel){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('nivel', $nivel);
        $res = $this->db->get('modulos');
        return $res->result();
    }
```

Con este usuario me funciona perfecto, el problema es con el administrador que necesito que le salgan los demás items, donde Alkosto es un item con módulos, pero los demás items también tienen.

un ejemplo seria para el otro item digo que es Exito y tiene como módulos Tarjeta exito y Tarjeta master card o tengo el item Hogar el cual tiene como modulos habitación, cocina, sala etc...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero ser clara en lo que necesito, cabe aclarar que esto es urgente y dar gracias de antemano a quien me pueda ayudar.

por último mi base de datos es la siguiente.

Login

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

modulos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en la tabla módulos no tienes nada con nivel 12 que es lo que pasas al concatenar el 1 y el 2.

Si necesitas que con el administrador se muestren todos los módulos, deberías de tener cuidado con el where de la consulta.

Podrías meter un if para saber si es administrador y saber si hacer el where o no.

```
function listar_modulos($nivel){
    $this->db->select('*');
    if($nivel != 12)
        $this->db->where('nivel', $nivel);
    $res = $this->db->get('modulos');
    return $res->result();
}
```

De esta manera el where solo se ejecutara cuando no sea la cuenta del administrador. también podrías pasar otro número en el if y filtrar por ese.

Comment: si esa era una prueba que estaba haciendo y se me olvido quitarlo antes de enviarlo, lo siento, la cosa es que cuando yo valido el nivel el administrador también me salen los niveles que tienen cero y esos me deberían llegar es en la etiqueta <a>, osea deberia poder validar la cantidad de niveles que tienen cero y así a cada nivel cero poder asignarle los modulos que le corresponden según el código

Comment: Entonces deberías de formular bien la pregunta.